# Android: Gradle error while migrating to dynamic-feature module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, dynamic-feature

I have been following the steps to migrate my multi-module app to the new dynamic-feature modules as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration) as the former has been deprecated.

I followed all steps and reviewed them too. But I am still getting the below errors which I am unable to understand.

All the errors pertain to the androidx libraries.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':installed_feature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: installed_feature


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:{strictly 2.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha04.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':forms@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: forms


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha06.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha06.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha06.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0-beta01.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':login@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha02.
Show Details
Affected Modules: login


WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'.
Affected Modules: base, forms, installed_feature, login
```

Comment: same issue here. only hello world sample from google works. As usual

Comment: share your gradle files

Comment: how did you resolve it? im having the same issue while trying to migrate a dynamic-module to lib-module

Comment: @MarceloJoy I didn't migrate... will do only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar issue [Could not resolve org.jetbrains:annotations:{strictly 13.0}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57512625/1079990) and I was able to solve it.

It means, you can give this a try :

```
android {
    ...

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Please removed it, as soon as the project compiles without it
            force 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0' // add more such items, if needed
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, when you share a github project with the error, it's much easier to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using these dependencies in my dynamic modules but I had not defined them in their build.gradle files.

Now, to avoid adding the same dependencies to each build.gradle, you can take your base module's build.gradle and write
`api androidx.lifecycle...` instead of `implementation androidx.lifecycle...` so the dependency can also be used by the dynamic modules.

Hope this helps!